# Upload file via URL

Tags: macos, google-chrome, upload

I'm a recent Mac convert. In Windows when I wanted to upload a file to a website I could do this (see the URL in the File Name text field):

[image: Windows' version]

However there's no way to do that in the upload dialog for Mac (notice, no text field to even do this in):

[image: Apple's version]

At least not that I'm aware of. This means that I have to actually download the file and then upload it using the dialog. I realize that the window's method actually downloads the file to a temp directory and then uploads it, but I don't have to think about that ("it just works").

Which is why I'm asking this question. Is there any application or any settings I could change to make this possible on my MacBook Pro? I'm running OS X 10.8.2 and my preferred browser is Chrome.

P.S. I realize that on this site there's a way to link with a URL, but on sites like Facebook and Google+ there is no option for that. :) Don't address this issue, that's not my question :) Thanks!

Comment: There's no built-in way to do that. Am I assuming right that in this scenario you have the URL of the image you want to upload in your clipboard?

Comment: @slhck Yes, if you look in the File name field in the windows example it has a url to a valid image. I was pretty sure that there was no built-in way. Do you know of any app or extension which could do this?

Comment: Some file hosters offer drag & drop support for uploading. Maybe it works with those?

Comment: A similar (unanswered) question at Ask Different: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48693.

Comment: Downloading the file from a URL to a temporary location, and getting the temp file path into the clipboard [is pretty easy](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=XZirBv7h), but I have no idea how to pass this to a Choose File dialog via AppleScript. (@LauriRanta, by chance?)

Answer (score -1):

Try Command + Shift + G  ( mnemonic: Go to ... )  This works in both finder and file dialogs.  also very helpful to get to hidden folders.

Comment: This doesn't work for URLs of remote images.